# My model is see-through with black lines

Tags: modeling

I'm pretty new to blender, so i apologize if this question is a little dumb, i was following a blender tutorial but i accidentally pressed a key and i don't know which one i pressed, and now my model is sort of see through, here's the picture[image]

Answer (score 4):

Probably, you pressed <kbd>Z</kbd> and then you changed the [viewport shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/display/shading.html?#viewport-shading) so now you are in wireframe shading.

Press <kbd>Z</kbd> to change to *Solid Shading* via the pie menu or use the topbar as shown below:

[image]